# How to add single quotes while parsing with jq?

Tags: bash, jq

Trying to parse a value from AWS CLI command using `jq` which should be in the following format:
`MY_KEY='MY_VALUE'`

Using the below command:
`<cli command> | jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.value["Name"], "=", "\"", .value["Value"], "\""] | @tsv' | tr -d "\t"`

With the above command, getting the output in double-quotes: `MY_KEY="MY_VALUE"`. However, I want the values to be enclosed in single quotes. What modifications can be done in the above command to achieve the same?

Syntax tried and not working: `'\''`, `"'"`

Comment: As a minimal solution, replacing the two instances of `"\""` with `"'"'"'"` will probably get you there, but your script makes a lot of redundant detours which you should address as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to escape for the shell, just use `@sh`:

```bash
<cli> | jq -r '.[] | "\(.Name)=\(.Value | @sh)"'
```

Comment: Thanks this works exactly the way I needed. However, I tested my script using both methods you shared in the comment as well in the answer and it works the same way. Which one would you suggest a better way to go ahead?

Comment: @marshmello Your initial approach (regardless of which kind of quotes it uses, and apart from the detours mentioned) just wraps the value in quotes. With `@sh`, on the other hand, the value is prepared all around for being used in a shell context (which includes quoting). This means, when being used in a shell, `@sh` covers certain cases where simple quoting wouldn't suffice (e.g. if the value itself contained the `'` character, `@sh` would likewise translate it to `'\''`). Therefore it depends on your use case what your actual goal is (only wrapping or full escaping).